# Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets gives 'Namespace Error' on inserting data?

Tags: php, zend-framework, insert, google-docs

I'm trying to insert a row in my Google spreadsheet. While other functions like counting rows, columns etc work fine; inserting a row gives me ['Namespace Error'](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?aff178b124.png).

```
An exception of type DOMException was thrown, but did not get caught during the execution of the request. You will find information provided by the exception along with a stack trace below.

Stack Trace
   1. at exception origin in ...\library\Zend\Gdata\App\Base.php line 220
   2. at Zend_Gdata_App_Base->getDOM([object DOMDocument], 1, NULL)
      in ...\library\Zend\Gdata\Spreadsheets\Extension\Custom.php line 64
   3. at Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_Custom->getDOM([object DOMDocument])
      in ...\library\Zend\Gdata\Spreadsheets\ListEntry.php line 77
   4. at Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry->getDOM()
      in ...\library\Zend\Gdata\App\Base.php line 329
   5. at Zend_Gdata_App_Base->saveXML()
      in ...\library\Zend\Gdata\Spreadsheets.php line 336
   6. at Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets->insertRow(array('xxx', 'xxx', 'Normal', 'Lease', 'xxx', 'test', 'test'), '0Aoxxx2c')
```

Comment: You'll need to paste your code for someone to help with this. This looks like a bug in the library, and should be reported through the Zend Framework issue tracker if so.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is from a while back, but I figured I'd post anyway in the hopes of saving someone else time and headaches.

I was having this same problem and after a lot of debugging it turns out that it happens due to malformed XML.

If you're passing Key values with spaces in them, it will trigger this error.

I solved it by removing all the characters that might give the XML parser trouble.

Hope that helps.